# How to run gui applications from aws vm connected using ssh?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, cloud, gedit

I have ubuntu installed on my system and I've created a linux aws ec2 instance. I connect to it using ssh. Now i need to run gui applications on it like gedit and all. But i get an error. How do i use gedit now with this?

Comment: Did any of the answers below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **ssh -X** option as:

```
ssh -X <username>@<ip>
```

More elegant way is using **tsvnc**, if you have software installation privilegies

```
sudo apt install x11vnc ssvnc
tsvnc <username>@<ip>
```

Then execute gedit as you would normally from console.

Alternatively, if text editor is the only GUI program you need you could try using a console based text-editor such as *nano* or *vim* using normal ssh connection.

Comment: I actually want to run applications like eclipse and android studio. Will ssh -X work?

Comment: It should, but it *tsvnc* might work better(it's what I usually use). Simplest way to find out is to try it out. If it doesn't work use *tsvnc* instead.

Alternatively, for Eclipse work you might want to check this out: http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install some separate applications to support, initially the cloud servers aren't meant for Graphical User Interface, and if you would love to just edit files you have nano and vim as options.

You need to install a light desktop environment like XFCE4 and VNC server for a good guide on how to install this check [this link](https://devopscube.com/setup-gui-for-amazon-ec2-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can always take a look at AWS Marketplace. Check Eclipse IDE, for instance: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-e7mobud4ole7y?ref_=dsk_products_all_prodview-e7mobud4ole7y_5